# RabbitMQ messages deleted from the queue automatically. How can I prevent it using Spring Boot?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

When the consumer consumes messages from the queue, then messages get automatically deleted from the queue. But I want to store them in the queue as long as I want. So is there any way in Spring Boot to store the RabbitMQ messages in the queue?